# Python beautifulsoup get text from current tag not from children

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = "<html>
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>
            <p class='a'>
               a        #(Text i want)
               <a>anchor</a>
            </p>
            <p class='b'>b</p>
        </body>
        </html>"

html = "<html>
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>
            <p class='a'>
               <a>anchor</a>
               a        #(Text i want)  (New Order)
            </p>
            <p class='b'>b</p>
        </body>
        </html>"


doml = BeautifulSoup(html)
tag = "p"
selector = "class"
selector_str = "a"
result = dom.find(tag, {selector: selector_str}, recursive=False, text=True)
print(result)    #result = None
```

This is what i have tried till now. how do i get the only text of class **a**.

I can't use the contents method:

```
dom = BeautifulSoup(html)
tag = "p"
selector = "class"
selector_str = "a"
result = dom.find(tag, {selector: selector_str})
print(result.contents[0])  #prints(a)
```

Because the text could be in any order. so anybody know how to accomplish this without using contents method?

Comment: do you always know what the children tags are

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yes

Comment: how about `tag = soup.find(attrs= {"class":"a"})tag.a.clear()print tag.text`

Comment: No prob. You're welcome